# File extension showing up after pretty URL rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a rewrite rule like so:

```
RewriteRule ^listings/?(.*)$ listings.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

I will have URLs like "site.com/listings/Awesome-Place-Or-Thing".  I would like `slug` to contain "Awesome-Place-Or-Thing" for this URL.  With the current rule, I get:

```
var_dump($_GET);

'slug' => string '.php/Awesome-Place-Or-Thing'
```

How do I get rid of the ".php/"?

Comment: Where is your slug being set? Removing that has nothing to do with your htaccess rule, it'd have to be removed in your PHP

Comment: "slug" is coming straight from the $_GET array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres the messy solution

```
RewriteRule ^listings/?\.php/(.*)$ listings.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Comment: +1 How did you figure out there was a *.php* string when the OP is saying the request is something like `site.com/listings/Awesome-Place-Or-Thing`, without that extension. By the server variables dump? Great deduction anyway, but I guess the OP should check the source of the requests to remove any unwanted strings. Something is wrong.